# Como fechar todas os forms que eu quero no C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Suponhamos que tenho 4 forms: `form1`, `form2`, `form3` e `form4`. Sabendo que a janela `form1` sempre será aberta primeiro e quando eu der um `.close()` na `form2` ela, juntamente com as outras, deverão fechar. Como faço para conseguir isso ? Lembrando que a `form1` deverá permanecer aberta e que isso não passa de uma suposição para que tenhamos uma resposta mais generalista que ajude mais pessoas.

Comment: Feche todas que deseja, qual a dificuldade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar uma classe de controle para armazenar todos os menus que você vai abrindo, onde ela vai guardar o menu que foi aberto e qual é seu menu "pai", exemplo:

```
public class MenusAbertos
{
  public Control Menu {get; set;}
  public string ClassePai {get; set;}
}

public class ListaMenusAbertos
{
  public list<MenusAbertos> Menus {get; set;}
}
```

Ai depois toda vez antes de fechar um menu, você busca nessa lista se algum deles é "filho" desse menu que você está fechando e se tiver filhos, você fecha eles antes e excluí da lista.

Answer (score 1):

Neste ponto vale ressaltar como você chama os demais forms, para assim ele fechar de acordo com a ordem de chamada, abaixo vou citar um exemplo que uso.

Antes de você ir chamando qualquer form pelo evento button_Click, vamos instanciar primeiro no começo de nosso form, primeiro vamos chamar de forma simples nossa form_2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Abrindo_e_Fechando_Forms
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form_2 MeuForm2 = null;
    public Form_3 MeuForm3 = null;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btn_abrir_form_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form_2 Form2 = new Form_2();
        Form2.Show();
      }

     }
 }
```

agora vamos fazer como com que, o Form2 chame o Form3, e quando clicar em fechar no form2 ele feche o forme 3

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Abrindo_e_Fechando_Forms
  {
      public partial class Form_2 : Form
   {
    public Form_3 MeuForm3 = new Form_3();

     public Form_2()
     {
          InitializeComponent();
     }

    private void btn_abrir_form_3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   

        MeuForm3.Show();
    }

       private void btn_fechar_formAtual_e_aberto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MeuForm3.Hide();
        this.Close();
    }


  }
}
```

Como você pode observar eu criei uma nova instancia de form3 no Form2

```
public Form_3 MeuForm3 = new Form_3();
```

Ou seja instanciando o Form3 ele se torna nosso objeto e podemos manipular da melhor forma possível. espero que isso tenha ajudado de alguma forma!

atte!